# Print an input given one word per line

Tags: c

When I input "Hello World", the output gives me 111111111111. It that what putchar() supposed to return or my code is wrong somewhere?

```
int main()
{   

int c;

    while ((c = getchar() != EOF)) {

        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            printf("\n");                   
        }

        else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` Note the `')'` move.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because:

```
while ((c = getchar() != EOF))
```

assigns `getchar() != EOF` to `c` which will be `true` or `1` for all but `EOF`. You need to move the closing `')'` after `EOF`, e.g.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

So you actually assign the result of `getchar()` to `c` before testing against `EOF`.